# Can I send turtle language to Apache Jena Fuseki?

Tags: sparql, owl, fuseki, swrl

I am currently fetching and creating rules in Apache Jena Fuseki for a project.

The things is that for the moment I am only able to get and post information via SPARQL which is great for fetching triplets, but very complicated to write and to read for creating rules.

Does anyone knows if Fuseki can accept Turtle or SWRL languages (much easier to understand)?

Thank you!

Comment: You can send Turtle by POSTing it with MIME type text/turtle. This is the SPARQL Graph Store protocol : https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-http-rdf-update/It does not use the SPARQL Update language. Client code: `GSP` or operations on an RDFConnection.

Comment: SWRL is a rule language, what should Fuseki do with it? Also, you would have to use an SWLR capable reasoner in Jena (e.g. Pellet) as the the Jena built-in rule language and SWRL are clearly not the same

Answer (score 0):

you have two easy way of requesting an Apache Jena-Fuseki server, either by using HTTP over SPARQL requests (What you are doing) or using triples requesting (turtle) with the python library "rdflib" which enables you to load your ontology or rdf triples into python and request jena with its SPARQL store plugin.

for SWRL rules it's a bit different since, like mentionned @UninformedUser you would need to configure your Jena with a Reasoner like Pellet/Openllet.

here are some links you can check :

- [rdflib](https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html)
- [SPARQL Over HTTP](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/fuseki2/soh.html)
- [Pellet with docker](https://github.com/giulianodelagala/CURIOCITY/blob/8c7329764f027275c33ef4f623cdbcdb62b6d143/Manuals/PelletReasonerJena.md) (could still be used to get pellet reasoner)
- [Adding reasoning](https://apothem.blog/apache-jena-fuseki-adding-reasoning-and-full-text-search-capabilities-to-a-dataset.html)